# state of checkbox is not saving however values are, What am i missing?

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, state, freemarker

Problem Detail: 
In itemCheckout.ftl (freemarker template) I have a drop-down box with check-box associated with it.When user selects value from drop-down and checks check-box for saving that item. Data and value of checkbox has to be saved for that user for next visits (until default value changes). In my case value has been saved correctly but not the check-box state.

Having Problem ( not checked )

```
<div id="item_default_checkbox" style="display: none"                       
    <label for="item_save_default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="item_save_default" onclick="itemFunction(this)" id="item_save_default" 
        <#if item_save_default?? && item_save_default["checked"]>
            checked="checked" 
        </#if>
        />${item_save_default["label"]!""}
        <#if item_save_default?? && item_save_default["tooltipText"] != "">
            <div id="item_save_default_help" class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
        </#if>
    </label>
</div>
```

FireBug inspect shows

```
<div id="item_default_checkbox">
    <label for="item_save_default">
        <input id="item_save_default" type="checkbox" onclick="itemFunction(this)" name="item_save_default">
        Save this item as default?
    </label>
</div>
```

What's not happening ?

```
<input id="item_save_default" type="checkbox" checked="checked"  onclick="itemFunction(this)" name="item_save_default">
```

i.e `checked="checked"`

Comment: so `<#if item_save_default?? && item_save_default["checked"]>` returns `false`

Comment: What does `<#if item_save_default??>${item_save_default.checked?string}<#else>Missing!</#if>` print? BTW `item_save_default?? && item_save_default["checked"]` can be written as `(item_save_default.checked)!false`.

Comment: I found out  `item_save_default??` is giving `true` where as `item_save_default["checked"]` returning `false`. Why so ?

Comment: Hey ddekany, `<#if shipping_save_address??>${shipping_save_default.checked?string}<#else>Missing!</#if>` returned `false` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event handler, `itemFunction`, is not being passed the state of the checkbox